# question regarding randbetween in excel and revenue

Tags: excel

The Doobie Brothers garage band is planning a concert. Tickets are set at $20. Based on what other bands have done, they figure they should sell 350 tickets, but that could fluctuate. They figure the standard deviation of sales at 50 tickets. No shows are uniformly distributed between 1 and 10. Fixed costs are 5000.

How profitable is the concert likely to be?
So I am able to enter the excel formula for revenue 50*20 and subtract 5000 for FC, but I am having trouble deciphering how to account for the no show costs. I know that I have to use RANDBETWEEN(1,10) formula, but I am not sure if it gets multiplied or divided by something. Again, I am looking for what to do with the formula in the context of a profit equation.

If it helps, the mean for the number of tickets sold is 350 and stdev is 50, so I used that to get the number of attendees in a simulated sense...That is, NORM.INV(RAND(),350,50)

Of course, this problem may not be realistic in real life because promoters keep the money, but for the purposes of the problem...just assume that no promoters exist here.

Comment: Is.. is this homework?

Comment: no it is not, it is a practice problem

Comment: I'm not clear on the meaning of "no shows". Is that people who purchase tickets but don't attend (meaning that you could potentially increase profit by selling a greater number of tickets than the capacity of the venue)?

Comment: *How profitable is the concert likely to be?* Unprofitable for the musicians, because the promoters keep all the money!

Comment: Okay, but that is too literal. I do not mean that. Assume there is no such middleman/promoter. And yes, no shows is people who purchase but do not attend

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused but if the mean is 350 tickets, with a standard deviation of 50, it's most likely amount of sold tickets should still be 350, right? Then just add a randomised number between 1 and 10 for extra tickets and multiply that by 20 for a ticket. Substract the 5000 and you'l get the most likely profit.

Comment: you are right thanks